# How to defineing a Pivot statement in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm having some problems with creating a pivot query:

I have this data:

```
DECLARE @UserAccess TABLE
(
    userName char(255),
    project char(255),
    role char(255)
);

userName  project  role
--------  -------  ----
ado       BI       U
aga       BI       D
aga       BI       U
mim       BI       A
mim       BI       U
ado       BID      D
ado       BID      U
aga       BID      D
aga       BID      U
mim       BID      A
mim       BID      D
mim       BID      U
```

What I would like is this:

```
User    BI    BID
-----   ---   ---
ado     U     DU
aga     DU    DU
mim     AU    ADU
```

But I can't figure out how to construct the statement to get this.

Comment: There is no inbuilt aggregate that will concatenate the roles for you as you desire. You could create a CLR UDA and then use `PIVOT` (if order of the concatenated elements is not important) or else you will need to use `XML PATH` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to concatenate the `roles` into a single row, then you can apply the PIVOT function:

```
select username, BI, BID
from
(
  select username, project, 
    STUFF((SELECT distinct '' + t.[role]
         from UserAccess t
         where u.username = t.username
           and u.project = t.project
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,0,'') role
  from UserAccess u
) d
pivot
(
  max(role)
  for project in (BI, BID)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d70a/6).

This can also be written using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
;with cte as
(
  select username, project, 
    STUFF((SELECT distinct '' + t.[role]
         from UserAccess t
         where u.username = t.username
           and u.project = t.project
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,0,'') role
  from UserAccess u
)
select username,
  max(case when project = 'BI' then role end) BI,
  max(case when project = 'BID' then role end) BID
from cte
group by username;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d70a/8)